# stop javascript loop, setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This animation should stop playing (stop snowing) after 10 seconds. I added a function to the bottom, but it actually starts the animation after 10 seconds, rather than stopping the animation after 10 seconds.

I only want it to play for 10 seconds total time, and start right-away, see my codePen to see what I mean.

```
setTimeout(function() {
createSnow(20);
loop();
}, 10000)
```

here is a codePen to see what I mean:
https://codepen.io/celli/pen/XzzjRW

Comment: the code suggests you *create snow* **after** waiting 10 seconds, then run loop, whatever that is

Comment: yes, but I am looking to stop the snow after 10 seconds... how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. You just needed a way to tell the system to stop the animation loop. See my codepen: https://codepen.io/intervalia/pen/zPPoBZ

I added a variable to indicate if animation should be happening:

```
var animating = true;
```

A routine to stop the animation:

```
function stopAnimation() {
  animating = false;
  //Add something in here to clear the screen
}
```

A validation check in the animation loop:

```
function loop() {
  if (animating) {
    draw();
    update();
    animFrame(loop);
  }
}
```

And changed your timeout to turn off the animation:

```
createSnow(150);
loop();

setTimeout(stopAnimation, 10000);
```

Cool animation!!

Comment: perfect :) and if I wanted the flakes that were falling at the end to fade out to opacity:0, how could I add that in ?

Comment: You can change the `animating` variable to a state instead of just `true`/`false`. Start it with a value of `snowing`, then change it to `fading` then `done` and have your animation loop do the correct thing based on that value.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is create a "timer", finding the difference between when you started and the current time.

I'm not sure if you wanted `createSnow(20)` inside of the loop or not, so I put it before, as initialization.

```
createSnow(20);

const start = new Date();
while(new Date() - start < 10000) {
  loop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cancelAnimationFrame`.

#### Sample usage

Declare `cancelAnimFrame`:

```
var cancelAnimFrame =
  window.cancelAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozcancelAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitcancelAnimationFrame ||
  window.mscancelAnimationFrame;
```

Update `loop` function:

```
var animId;
function loop() {
  draw();
  update();
  animId = animFrame(loop);
}
```

and use `animId` to stop animation.
(As already mentioned, starting snowing should be out of `setTimeout`.)

```
createSnow(20);
loop();
setTimeout(function() {
  cancelAnimFrame(animId)
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score -1):

the only thing that you have to change is a little change of your code plz see this code below :

```
var timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
createSnow(20);
loop();
}, 10000);

clearTimeout(timeOut);
```

Comment: this doesn't seem tot work. I am trying to make the snow stop after 10 seconds.